# How to specify Has_many order

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many

How do I assign a specific order in a Has_many relationship?

```
class GolfCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_nines
end

class CourseNine < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :golf_courses
end
```

Each `GolfCourse` will have two `CourseNines` and I'd like to specify/assign one `CourseNine` as the `first/front` and a `second one` as the `second/back`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class GolfCourse < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :course_nines do
    def front_nine
      order("created_at asc").first() #or whatever logic you want
    end
    def back_nine
      order("created_at desc").first() #or whatever logic you want
    end
  end
end
```

this example assumes you always have 2 NineCourses for every GolfCourse. There are other ways to potentially do it but you would need to provide some more details of what you want to do

Comment: Thanks for the response Tom. I don't/can't assign by time because they may be created out of order. For example, a golf club can have 3 Course_Nines (A,B,C). So a GolfCourse can be A+B, B+C, C+A. In this case, I want to specify that C is the front_nine and A is the back_nine

Comment: I would add a "course_order" integer column in the course_nines model/table and then tweak the solution above to use order("course_order asc") and order("course_order desc") for front_nine and back_nine methods respectively